# Привязка двух CollectionViewSource к одной коллекции ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, xaml, mvvm

Здравствуйте!
Есть общий пулл моделей, если можно так сказать, который находится в обновляемой коллекции ObservableCollection.

```
//...MainWindowViewModel.cs

ObservableCollection<ItemModel> Models{ get; set; } //модели добавляются-удаляются туда

/*есть еще пара коллекций, которые должны быть привязаны к общему пуллу: но отображать элементы, фильтруя их в соответствии с конкретной логикой, при необходимости можно было редактировать их */

CollectionViewSource GoodModels { get; set; }
CollectionViewSource ErrorModels { get; set; }

//и сделал фильтры для них
GoodModels.Filter += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var item = e.Item as ItemModel;
                if (item != null)
                {
                    e.Accepted = item.State == ModelState.Ok;
                }
            };

            ErrorModels.Filter += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var item = e.Item as ItemModel;
                if (item != null)
                {
                    e.Accepted = item.State != ModelState.Ok;
                }
            };

//...MainView.xaml

//В ресурсах создал 2 коллекции и привязал их к свойству Source (я пробовал и ко View)
<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Path=GoodModels.Source}" x:Key="src1"/>
<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Path=ErrorModels.Source}" x:Key="src2"/>

//отображаются они в DataGrid'ах, у каждого свой
  <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource src1}}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False">
    ...
    </DataGrid>

<DataGrid Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource src2}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False">
...
</DataGrid>
```

На выходе две одинаковые таблицы с одинаковым количеством моделей, т.е. неотфильтрованные совсем, чистая коллекция Models. Что я делаю не так?

При обновлении представлений GoodModels и ErrorModels (View.Refresh()) в лямбда выражение заходит, и все обновляется правильно, но отображаются другие данные.

Как сделать правильно? Благодарю за ответы.

Comment: `Binding Path=GoodModels.Source`

Биндиться надо к `GoodModels.View`, тогда Вы увидите отфильтрованые данные.

Comment: Source хоть что-то показывает, а View - пустые таблицы, я пробовал и так, и так (в коде во View есть модели, тестовые данные такие, что 2 листа должны отображаться

Comment: @Павел Петров, проверьте, выполняется ли условие фильтрации хотя бы для одного объекта.

Comment: @Donil выполняется для 3х в списке goodModels и для 7ми в списке errorModels

Comment: Эээ... А зачем вы создаёте в XAML'е новые `CollectionViewSource` и крадёте `Source` у существующих моделей? У новых `CollectionViewSource` точно нет фильтра, так что так точно не заработает.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Давайте набросаем пример. Описываем ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<int> _items; // Общая коллекция
    private readonly CollectionViewSource _positiveItems; // Положительные числа
    private readonly CollectionViewSource _negativeItems; // Отрицательные числа

    public ViewModel()
    {
        _items = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        // Наполняем коллекцию
        var random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            _items.Add(random.Next(100) - 50);
        }
        // Положительные числа
        _positiveItems = new CollectionViewSource();
        _positiveItems.Source = _items;
        _positiveItems.Filter += (s, e) => e.Accepted = (int)e.Item >= 0; // Больше либо равные нулю
        // Отрицательные числа
        _negativeItems = new CollectionViewSource();
        _negativeItems.Source = _items;
        _negativeItems.Filter += (s, e) => e.Accepted = (int)e.Item < 0; // Меньше нуля
    }

    public CollectionViewSource PositiveItems
    {
        get { return _positiveItems; }
    }

    public CollectionViewSource NegativeItems
    {
        get { return _negativeItems; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<int> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
    }
}
```

В конструкторе View прописываем контекст данных:

```
public MainWindow()
{
   var vm = new ViewModel();
   DataContext = vm;
   InitializeComponent();
}
```

Теперь в `XAML` прописываем наш интерфейс:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Все эелементы">
            <DataGrid
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn
                        Header="Число"
                        Binding="{Binding Path=.}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </TabItem>

        <TabItem Header="Положительные">
            <DataGrid 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PositiveItems.View}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn
                        Header="Число"
                        Binding="{Binding Path=.}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </TabItem>

        <TabItem Header="Отрицательные">
            <DataGrid 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=NegativeItems.View}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn
                        Header="Число"
                        Binding="{Binding Path=.}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>

        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Вот, собственно, и все. В первой вкладке будет отображаться весь список чисел, во второй положительные, а в третьей отрицательные.

Я бы еще не отдавал всю `CollectionViewSource`, а только ее свойство `View`, но это уже как Вам будет удобнее.

Answer (score 0):

[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd), я по-разному пробовал и без создания коллекций в xaml'е.
Сейчас отказался от CollectionViewSource и заменил на ICollectionView, нормально работает.